# Model validation is not working for fields in self-hosted web api application

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Recently we would like to add [model validation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) logic using data annotation approach to our existing web api project. What we have discovered is that some validation attributes do not work for fields of the model, but works for properties:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApp.Start("http://*:80/", app =>
        {
            HttpConfiguration cfg = new HttpConfiguration();
            cfg.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            app.UseWebApi(cfg);
        });

        Console.WriteLine("The server has been started");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [ValidateModel]
    [Route]
    public void Post([FromBody]Model model)
    {
        string p = model == null ? "model is null" :
                   string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Required) ? "required is null" : 
                   model.Required;
        Console.WriteLine($"Passed model is: {p}");
    }
}

public class Model
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Required; // Model validation does not works
    //public string Required { get; set; } - Model validation works
}

public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing

```
POST http://localhost/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: sb1124
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "wtf" : "ftw"
}
```

Give to us:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 05:54:43 GMT
```

Which looks like incorrect behavior, IMHO, even though the article state that:

> In ASP.NET Web API, you can use attributes from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace to set validation rules for **properties** on your model.

I have tried to create nested validation attribute from the **RequiredAttribute**, and override the `IsValid` methods, but the breakpoints were not hitted there. One workaround is to modify our models in order to use properties.

Why this design decision was made to validate only properties, but not fields? Is there any other workaround which helps to avoid model changing?

---

In order to execute this console app, use Packcage Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
```